# How to adjust the inner and outer margin spaces around legend in PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

How can I adjust the inner/out right/left/top/bottom margins of legend in PGFPlots? (not the space between the legend entries)
e.g. indicated in the below figure.

[image]

Comment: For "inner" margins try `legend style={inner sep=0pt}`; outer margins is different: first they depend where the legend goes. You can always use `legend style={at={(x,y)}}` to fine customize the position.

Comment: Thanks you. For outer margin even when I use `legend style={at=({1,1}),anchor=south east}` I get a little space between the edge of the plot and the legend box, how to remove that space?

Comment: Add `every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}`, the legend, as I recall, is a `\matrix` hence a node. If you then need the spacing inside the legend, put another inner/outer sep in the legend style.

Comment: Did the tip of zeroth help you or do you need further assistance?